# How to change all <option> Text in SelectPicker

Tags: jquery

I need to change the text in all `<option ...> ... </option>` elements of a dropdown that uses jQuery SelectPicker. None of the values should be effected.

Initially, when the options are populated there is a placeholder of `XX` in the option text. For example:

```
GHO.502/TT3-XX04-F.P1
```

All of the option texts have this similar format. I need to iterate through each option text, change the `XX` value and save the change.

The change is dependent on another control which could change back and forth, but the `XX` is obviously gone after the first change. So I thought I could save the initial `<select>` in document.ready:

```
_savedSelect = $('#mySelect');
```

At this point I can iterate through _savedSelect when needed, read the default texts containing the `XX` placeholders, modify each and then save them to the `<option>` elements of the actual `<select>`.

After modifying all texts:

```
$("#mySelect").selectpicker('refresh');
```

But I'm not sure how to iterate all options in the saved select, get the text of each, replace the `XX` placeholder and then save it to the actual select options.

Could anyone give me an idea on how to do this?

**EDIT**

I've worked out part of the .each:

```
$("#mySelect > option").each(function () {
    $newtext = HOW TO GET CORRESPONDING TEXT FROM _savedSelect??;
    this.text = $newtext.replace( 'XX', $('#someInput').val() );
});

$("#mySelect").selectpicker('refresh');
```

How do I get the corresponding text value from the saved select?

**UPDATE**

One of @madalinivascu's answers works somewhat, but not completely:

```
$("#mySelect> option").each(function () {
    $textarr = $(this).text().split('XX');
    $newtext = $textarr[0] + $('#someInput').val() + $textarr[1];
    $(this).text($newtext);
});
```

But this will only work the first time the input control is changed since `XX` gets replaced. In my description above I mentioned saving the initial state of `#mySelect` in a variable. This way I will always have the text strings with placeholders in them - my problem is I don't know how to access the text values inside of the saved variable.

Comment: use $.each to loop the options

Comment: why aren't you doing this on the serverside?

Comment: @madalinivascu This is a client specification. The XX changes according to user input on the frontend. There can be up to a couple hundred options in the select dropdown. An Ajax round trip would be very slow for sure. I'm not even so sure I can do it on the frontend quickly enough. It could be done on the serverside, but it wouldn't make any sense and only take longer.

Comment: why do you need ajax for altering server side code ma, lol?

Comment: @madalinivascu I don't understand why you're going in this direction. Lol? Why do the superfluous string replace on the server side? It's in an ASP.NET MVC web app. The page is already rendered, now I may need to modify select dropdown text. You asked why I don't do it on the serverside... are you proposing to reload the entire page? I don't want to go into that much detail with you. You're not making any sense on this side, though I'm sure you feel you are on your side.

Comment: when you generate the select why don't you generate it with the replaced text?

Comment: It's a model number and the XX represents part of a nomenclature. It's not in a database except for with the XX. When a user selects a specific number of an accessory for this product, the XX represents that specification. There is no way of predicting this on the server side.

Comment: you mean you have another element on the page that gives the values for the xx?

Comment: Sure. That's in my question, er it was supposed to be. I see I left that out. Sorry. XX represents a value from another control on the page which the user can select. It ranges from 2 to 36 and increments by 2 (even numbers). A user could sit and click up and down - I'm not sure that the jQuery can replace the texts that fast and that's what I'm wanting to test. I don't like this, but I'm not seeing another solution, yet. :S

Comment: @madalinivascu I edited my question to include the .each loop I put together so far. I'm just not understanding how to get the option texts using the variable - I know I could do it like this: `$("#mySelect[value='2']").text()` - but _savedSelect is a variable so the selector method don't work.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, clone the select after page load, loop it and based on the value of cloned element change the on page elements text to the desired text

```
$cloned = $("#mySelect").clone();

$('input').on('change',function(){
 $cloned.find('option').each(function () {
    $textarr= $(this).text().split('XX');
    console.log($textarr);

    $newtext =  $textarr[0]+$('input').val()+$textarr[1];
    $("#mySelect > option[value='"+$(this).val()+"']").text($newtext);
 });
});
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/egu3wo8k/1/

Comment: This is very helpful, except that the only placeholder I can rely on is the `XX` (uppercase btw). The hyphens are not predictable or shouldn't be considered predictable. Also, after the texts are changed for the first time the `XX` is no longer available - for the next time the radio button is clicked and it needs to be changed again. That's why I saved initial state in _savedSelect - it will contain the list and all of the model numbers with the `XX` placeholder.

Comment: If this were my choice I would have the nomenclature down tight and everything would be precisely predictable. It's not my choice though. I've been asked to make it work. :P

Comment: I edited my question with an update. Hopefully makes it clearer what the problem is.

Comment: But yes, your jsfiddle is the desired result, but if you index ONLY off of the XX it will no longer work. You are using the hyphens as placeholders... and since the XX is gone after the first change I need to use a variable containing the initial saved state of the select control.

Comment: You newest jsfiddle works great! Thank you. I'm going to study what you did, I see the .find(). Nice. :)